# How to conditionally code a new variable based on checking multiple columns for multiple values

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to search a series of values (ICD9 code list  or ICD10 code list) within a group of variables (DX1-DX5) conditional of DXVER=9 search the ICD9 list and DXVER=10 search the ICD10 list.  This is possible to write out by hand but because the variables and code lists can be longer I want to learn to do this by referring to the groups by a name.

I have tried if else statement, rowsum, and coding each individual step.  These can work although I'm always missing one step out of the three requirements. 
1. conditional on DXVER
2. refer to DXS for the list of DX1-DX5
3. refer to ICD9 and ICD10 for the code list

```
ICD9 <- c('042', '7953', '79571', 'V08')
ICD10 <- c('888', 'a10', 'b10', '987')

DXS <- c(paste('DX', seq(1:5), sep = '')) 

MergedData<-data.frame(DXVER=c("9", "9", "0", "0", "9"),
                   DX1 = c('042',"1","1","2","1"),
                   DX2 = c("4","3",'2',"4","3"),
                   DX3 = c("2","2","4","2","2"),
                   DX4 = c("3",'101',"2","3","2"),
                   DX5 = c('79571',"3",'888',"2","2"),
                   ID  = c(345, 123, 246, 432, 121))

MergedData$HIV_claim<NA
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX1 %in% ICD9 & MergedData$DXVER=="9"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX2 %in% ICD9 & MergedData$DXVER=="9"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX3 %in% ICD9 & MergedData$DXVER=="9"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX4 %in% ICD9 & MergedData$DXVER=="9"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX5 %in% ICD9 & MergedData$DXVER=="9"] <- 
1 

MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX1 %in% ICD10 & MergedData$DXVER=="0"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX2 %in% ICD10 & MergedData$DXVER=="0"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX3 %in% ICD10 & MergedData$DXVER=="0"] <- 
1    
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX4 %in% ICD10 & MergedData$DXVER=="0"] <- 
1 
MergedData$HIV_claim[MergedData$DX5 %in% ICD10 & MergedData$DXVER=="0"] <- 
1 


 MergedData2 <- MergedData

 MergedData2$HIV_claim9<NA
MergedData2$HIV_claim10<NA
MergedData2$HIV_claim9 <-  ((rowSums(MergedData2[, DXS] == ICD9,  na.rm=T) 
> 0) * 1)
MergedData2$HIV_claim10 <- ((rowSums(MergedData2[, DXS] == ICD10, na.rm=T) 
> 0) * 1)

MergedData2$HIV_claim  <-  ifelse(MergedData2$DXVER == 9, 
ifelse(MergedData2$DX1 %in% ICD9 |  MergedData2$DX2 %in% ICD9
 |  MergedData2$DX3 %in% ICD9 |  MergedData2$DX4 %in% ICD9
|  MergedData2$DX5 %in% ICD9,1,0),0)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? For each patient/ID, are you trying to determine if their HIV_claim should be 1 (or NA) based on their DX1-5 and DXVER?

Comment: Yes you have understood what I am aiming to do.  HIV_claim is 1 if the codes I am looking for are found in DX1-DX5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

md %>% gather(dx,v,-DXVER,-ID) %>% 
  mutate(hiv = ifelse((v %in% ICD9 & DXVER=='9') | (v %in% ICD10 & DXVER=='0'),1,NA)) %>% 
  filter(hiv==1) %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(1) %>% 
  select(ID,hiv) %>% left_join(md,.)

Joining, by = "ID"
  DXVER DX1 DX2 DX3 DX4   DX5  ID hiv
1     9 042   4   2   3 79571 345   1
2     9   1   3   2 101     3 123  NA
3     0   1   2   4   2   888 246   1
4     0   2   4   2   3     2 432  NA
5     9   1   3   2   2     2 121  NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution @kstew.  I had not thought to gather my data to be longwise.  Do you know why the first row is repeating?  ID 345 shows up twice now in the table above.

Comment: I think I realized what is happening.  If hiv=1 from more than one of DX1-DX5, for example "042" and "79571" in row 1, the row repeats twice.  When this occurs I want the row to only appear once.  Is there a way to adjust the code for this?

Comment: Good catch. You can add a `group_by()` and `slice(1)` to remove any repeats by ID. I have edited my answer.